# Area Size of Plotted Squares

Tags: matlab, octave, area

I'm trying to calculate the area total area of scattered squares just like the image below.

I know there are a function with which we could estimate the area size by making  a comprehensive convex, but I'm not sure whether I can use some similar method to solve this.

Does anyone has a good idea?

Image: [image]

Edit[01/01/2016]:
The code I tried is like this. It works, but every time it has to save and load a .png image. I wanted to ask if it is possible to calculate the size without the process of saving images.

```
clear

b=zeros(127,2); %matrix

for i=1:127
    rnd=randn(1,2);
    b(i,:)=30.*rnd;
end

BW=scatter(b(:,1),b(:,2),15,[],'r','s','filled');

view(2) %view from Z+
axis off
saveas(gcf,'scatter.png')

close all

BWbase = imread('scatter.png'); %import
BW = im2bw(BWbase,0.5); %convert to binary data
imshow(BW);
bwarea(BW)
```

Comment: Have you tried any code so far? SO is _not_ a coding service and if you show us what you've tried, people will be more likely to help you.

Comment: Thank you for advice. I've added a note to clarify the point.

Comment: `BW=scatter(b(:,1),b(:,2),15,[],'r','s','filled');` gives an error. Try to fix your code first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You do not need to save and load the image** if you know proper functions. Your code has some issues that I fixed and I will explain here:

1- you do not need to initialize `b` with zeros and then fill it using a for-loop by random values. Instead you can do all that in one line of code:

```
b = 30 * randn(127,2);
```

2- Then you plot the points using `scatter`. I have removed `[]` to fix the command.

```
BW = scatter(b(:,1),b(:,2),15,'r','s','filled');
```

Note that this is not an image but a figure that you need to convert to an image. The function you are seeking is `getframe`. This function records a frame from a figure. You can call it by providing it with the current figure `gcf`.

```
F = getframe(gcf);
```

4- Now your frame in stored in `F` but it is not an image yet. To convert it to an image you need to use `frame2im` function.

```
[X, Map] = frame2im(F);
```

5- Then, as you did yourself, you convert the image to binary and calculate the area:

```
BW2 = im2bw(X,0.5); 
bwarea(BW2)
```

The whole code can be seen here:

```
b = 30 * randn(127,2);
BW = scatter(b(:,1),b(:,2),15,'r','s','filled');
axis off
F = getframe(gcf);
[X, Map] = frame2im(F);
BW2 = im2bw(X,0.5); 
imshow(BW2);
bwarea(BW2)
```

[image]

For more information check out the following documentations: [getframe](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html), [frame2im](http://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/frame2im.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 

In fact the code you showed was not available in my environment (Octave 3.x). After all I managed the task by saving and reloading the image for certain times.

Sorry for delay confirmation and thanks again for your suggestion.